# react-app сбивается код

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

может ли мне кто-то помочь? это началось после установки реакта(см скрин), вношу изменения, сохраняю и [image: введите сюда описание изображения]весь код сбивается? поотключал уже все возможные плагины - не помогает

С чем это связано и как исправить?

Спасибо

Comment: напишите ide который используете и список плагинов. Как видно у вас установлен beautify, попробуйте его отключить

Comment: А если  js  на  jsx  поменять?

Comment: вроде помогло, надеюсь дальше не начнет делать мозг) надо ведь просто расширение файла в ручную поменять, я правильно понял?)